# Upgrading Zend 1.x to Zend 2.X

Tags: php, zend-framework, scripting, zend-framework2

```
try
{ 
$dbo = Zend_Db::factory('pdo_mysql', array( 
    'host'     => DB_HOST, 
    'username' => DB_USER, 
    'password' => DB_PW, 
    'dbname'   => DB_PREFIX.DB_NAME
)); 
$dbo->getConnection();
// save database adapter for easy usage in other classes
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($dbo);
Zend_Registry::set('db', $dbo);

}
catch(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception $e)
{
  print $e; 
}
```

I want to upgrade this code with zend 2.X and i am using ZF2 as a standalone library without employing the full MVC framework.
my folder structure is:

```
   library/
          /Zend
          /Mylib
   css/
   img/
   js/
```

My autoload code is:

```
 require_once 'Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$autoLoader = new \Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
    'fallback_autoloader' => true,
));

 $autoLoader->register();
```

Also want to know how to work with database session? i.e storing session into database.
and can i use Zend 1.x methods in Zend 2.x project?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Structure of `Zend1` can not upgrade to `Zend2` but we can use `Zend2` methods and libraries in my project as parallel.

Steps:

1.copy `Zend2` libraries to a path

2.Add this code to `index.php`

```
define('ZF2_PATH', '/path/to/zf2/library');
require_once ZF2_PATH . '/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php';
$loader = new Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader(array(
    'autoregister_zf' => true,
));
$loader->register();
```

3.use namespaces of `Zend2` in your code for example in your controllers